# Protect contact form API

Tags: python, api, flask, authorization

I have a contact form on my website and I need to protect the API which recives the POST from it. Is there any way to force the API to accept only data from that form and prevent anyone to send post requestes without authorization?
I saw that there are different ways to authorize the client and create tokens but I don't understand how can I safely embed the auth token inside the request on the frontend

Comment: Are you submitting the form with an ajax call?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but embed a static token/password in the call would be useless

Comment: Do you use flask wtf for your forms?

Comment: No, I'm not. Sould I?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use JWT token-based authentication to transmit data stateless from client to server. Send the token in the Authorization header.

The Sequence will be like this,

- The client sends the login request, the server validates the user credentials and responds with a token.
- The client will store the token and sends the token along with all subsequent requests.
- On the server-side, we need to decode and validate the token, if the token is valid we can respond to the request.

You can use flask-jwt-extended,

https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/